# Rebus: I No Money

Tags: rebus

My first rebus puzzle got solved pretty quickly so I decided to make another one.
This time I tried making it a tad bit harder

[image]

Comment: My eyes are not on the money?

Comment: Even if that was the correct answer i can't approve it!!
Just to be clear.... wrong answer

Comment: eyes knows where is money

Comment: I'm sorry... you're wrong as well!!
Try harder guys!!1 :D

Comment: both eyes on money

Comment: nuh uh! :P try again!

Comment: Hmm... is there a way we can create better titles for these questions?

Comment: If there is one please let me know

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I think it's: put your money where your mouth is. Because the two eyes represent the eyes and the two no's the nose so the money is placed where there should be your mouth.

Comment: corrrrectt..good job!!

Comment: Yiiiiiieeeeepppppiiieeee! My first right answer! Thank you so much @TheDragonista :D

Comment: How can one face have two noses?

Comment: Either those are nostrils or ears that can smell things.

Comment: @smci - There's not two noses, there's a plural of the word "no". I.e. the first row has "i"s (eyes), the second row has "no"s (or nose), etc

Comment: Ya the plural no's also sounds like singular nose. So only one nose.

Comment: The plural of no is noes

Answer (score 2):

Could it be:

Small eyes, no ears and money talks.

Because it looks like a face.

Comment: nope, that isn't it